# Как добраться до DbSet<T>.Count() через рефлексию?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, рефлексия

Я могу получить и вызвать метод  `DbSet<T>.Add()` через рефлексию:

```
void AddNewEntity (DbContext db, string entityType, object newEntity)
{
    PropertyInfo dbSetProp = typeof(Models.Entities)
        .GetPrperty(entityType);
    MethodInfo dbSetAddMethod = dbSetProp
        .PropertyType
        .GetMethod(nameof(DbSet<object>.Add));
    object dbSet = dbSetProp.GetValue(db);
    dbSetAddMethod.Invoke(dbSet, new object[] { newEntity }); 
}
```

А как получить и вызвать метод `Count` ? Проблема в том, что это метод расширения, но как эту проблему решить?

Comment: А зачем вам через рефлексию? Вы не знаете тип заранее?

Comment: Метод расширения - это в первую очередь статический метод. Его можно вызвать как и любой другой: `Enumerable.Count()` или `Queryable.Count()` в вашем случае

Comment: @VladD, да, передаётся строка с именем типа. Перейти к нормальному использованию EF можно только через гигантский `switch`, хотя может так и лучше, но пока развлекаюсь с рефлексией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно подсказал @АндрейNOP, метод расширения это по сути статический метод из `Queryable.Count()`. Есть две перегрузки метода, различающиеся кол-во параметров. Поэтому, если нужен аналог вызова `DbSet<T>.Count()` (без параметров), значит выбор за перегрузкой `Count<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source);` (с одним параметром).

```
int EntityCount (DbContext db, string entityType)
{
    PropertyInfo dbSetProp = typeof(Models.Entities)
        .GetProperty(entityType);
    MethodInfo countMethod = typeof(Queryable)
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(t => t.Name == nameof(Queryable.Count))
        .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1);         
    Type type = Assembly
        .GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Single
        (
             t =>
                t.Namespace == $"{nameof(MyNameSpace)}.{nameof(Models)}"
                && t.Name == entityType
        );
    MethodInfo dbSetCountMethod = CountMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
    object dbSet = dbSetProp.GetValue(db);
    return Convert.ToInt32(dbSetCountMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbSet })); 
}
```