# Как через обобщенный метод получить количество строк в EF таблице?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

У меня есть класс DataProvider, в нем свойство Context с объектом-наследником Ef'овского контекста.

```
public class DataProvider
{
    private CargoDbContext Context { get; }
    ...
```

Соответственно, через этот Context я могу получить доступ к таблицам, количеству записей и т.д.:

```
var carsCount = Context.Cars.Count();
```

Хочу сделать в DataProvider обобщенный метод, чтобы узнавать количество записей как-то так:

```
var data = new DataProvider();
var carsCount = data.FetchCount<Cars>();
```

Написал вот такую реализацию:

```
public int FetchCount<T>()
{
    string tableName = typeof(T).Name;
    var efTable = Context.GetType().GetProperty(tableName);
    var countMethod = efTable.GetType().GetMethod("Count");

    return (int)countMethod.Invoke(efTable, null);
}
```

Размышлял так: в EF есть классы сущностей по именам таблиц в БД. У ef контекста есть свойства с именами такими же как у классов сущностей и эти свойства - суть DbSet, у которых можно запросить метод Count().

Значит я указываю методу тип, получаю имя типа в виде строки и получаю на контексте свойство с таким именем. Это будет DbSet. На нем я получаю метод Count и вызываю этот метод, передавая в качестве экземпляра этот самый DbSet. И все вроде бы идет неплохо: в efTable действительно лежит значение типа DbSet, но вот countMethod упорно остается null. Я пробовал еще вызывать вот так .GetMethod("Count", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance), но это не помогает.

Как в итоге сделать правильно такую задачу?

Comment: А вы нажмите на метод Count с зажатым Ctrl (или воспользуйтесь другим способом перехода к определению метода если у вас не VS2019, а что-то другое) и посмотрите где на самом деле этот метод находится...

Comment: Ну и плюс обратите внимание на метод [DbContext.Query<TQuery>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.query?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Query__1)

Comment: Я подозревал, что он не непосредственно в этом классе находится. А как правильно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787116/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-dbsett-count-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовавшись ссылкой @4per, я адаптировал его решение для своего вопроса и получил следующий метод:

```
public class DataProvider
{
    private CargoDbContext Context { get; }
    ...

    public int FetchCount<T>()
    {
        MethodInfo countMethod = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(Queryable.Count))
            .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

        var dbSet = Context.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(T).Name).GetValue(Context);
        return (int)countMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbSet });
    }
```

UPD. Оказалось, можно сделать проще, без рефлексии:

```
public int FetchCount<T>() where T : class
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Count();
}
```

Кроме того, это оказалось особенно удобно в более сложном фрагменте, задействующем уже несколько методов:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FetchRange<T>(int startIndex, int count) where T : class
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Skip(startIndex).Take(count);
}
```

Comment: А теперь на первую ссылку посмотрите. Вам вообще не нужна рефлексия.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, человек привел рабочий пример, который мне помог. Вы же привели ссылку на страницу без примеров, где к тому же "Warning This API is now obsolete". Хотите действительно помочь - приведите пример как использовать. Считаете, что это слишком очевидно, чтобы писать, ну, тогда я не знаю, зачем вообще заходить и что-то отвечать. Для вас - очевидно, для меня например нет, поэтому я и ищу тут помощи, чтоб посмотреть как надо. А минусовать рабочее решение, ну, тут уж без комментариев.

Comment: С другой стороны по ссылке Pavel Mayorov можно найти, что рекомендован метод Set. А значит вам можно заменить реализацию на  `return Context.Set<T>().Count();` или `return Context.Set<T>().CountAsync();`

Comment: @pinkertem решение через рефлексию и рабочее решение - это две большие разницы

Comment: @4per, не работает. Ошибка "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'". Т.е. мы ведь можем вызвать метод с любым типом, даже не подходящим var cnt = FetchCount<string>(); например, а это было бы неправильно, поэтому он не  компилит такой вариант.

Comment: @pinkertem ну так добавьте ограничение в свой метод. Всё равно вы с value-типами работать не сможете.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, каким образом добавить ограничения? Через where T : перечислить все классы таблиц БД?

Comment: просто `where T : class`

Comment: @4per, спасибо, получилось.
P.S. Три раза пересмотрел эту страницу, чтобы найти, где же там написано Set использовать вместо Query. Ну они конечно нашли наверное идеально неподходящее место для этого)