# С# рефлексия и Entity Framework. Можно ли выполнить метод ToList()?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Надеюсь тут есть гуру c# которые могут мне помочь.
Итак, есть контекст БД в переменной по имени db. У неё есть свойства DbSet, имя каждого свойства соответствует имени таблички БД. Всё что я хочу сделать - это получить свойство по имени (что у меня в коде уже прекрасно работает), а затем выполнить для этого свойства метод ToList(). Проблема в том, что GetMethod не может по какой-то причине найти данный метод (хотя вызовом "напрямую" он спокойно вызывается). Код, который должен по идее работать, приведён ниже:

```
Type baseTableType = db.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
PropertyInfo filteringProperty = baseTableType.GetProperty(filteringPropertyName);
var table = db.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(db);
var toListM = table.GetType().GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));
List<object> somelist = toListM.Invoke(table, null) as List<object>;
```

Comment: Потому что ToList это метод расширения, а не метод класса. Напишите как вы вызываете его "напрямую" и нажмите F12 в студии, увидите к какому классу он относится

Comment: @АндрейNOP получается рефлексией нет вариантов его получить?

Comment: @MichaelKuma4ov, есть, просто получать надо из другого класса. В данном случае из [`Queryable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=net-6.0)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787116/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-dbsett-count-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e

Answer (score 0):

Проблема действительно решилась благодаря комментарию [@АндрейNOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366516/%d0%a1-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-entity-framework-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-tolist/1366556#comment2425351_1366516).

Изменил:

```
var toListM = table.GetType().GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));
```

На:

```
var toListM = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));
```